# Sencha Architect 3 Stop Working

Tags: sencha-architect

Sencha Architect 3 is not running anymore on Ubuntu 16.10.

I got this error:

```
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072190766:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: ocsp.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072190885:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: ocsp.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072190956:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: crl4.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072192522:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: ocsp.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072192575:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: ocsp.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072192639:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: crl4.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072192682:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: crl3.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072194352:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: ocsp.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072194401:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: ocsp.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072194469:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: crl4.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072196319:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: ocsp.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072196366:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: ocsp.digicert.com
[7577:7601:0106/193443:3072196431:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(612)] No URLRequestContext for NSS HTTP handler. host: crl4.digicert.com
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.4Lts

First:

```
cd ~/.local/share/Sencha
$ sudo rm -rf ~/SenchaArchitect3
```

Second:

```
$ sudo ./start.sh
```

Comment: Are you able to elaborate at all on why this is a solution? Just giving commands (especially where one of them is potentially dangerous - `rm -rf`) doesn't really help anyone.